# link to nested ressource in each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, nested-resources

I have an Array of various ActiveRecord Objects which are Objects of different Models. One of them is called `Team` which is a nested ressource of `Department`:

```
resources :departments do
  resources :teams
end
```

So when I use this in the `array.each` like this:

```
array.each do |element|
  link_to element.name, element
end
```

It throws an error that `team_path` doesnt exist whats logical because of nested ressources the route is called `department_team_path` but I cant call this method absolutely because I also treat Objets of other Models in this `each`.

One posibility I see is to add a Route called team_path whih refers to Team#Show but thats not pretty and also bad for the SEO. Is there another better possibility to link to this and other models in one course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own methods to deal with this problem. They are located in `ApplicationHeler`

```
def nested_name(object)
    routes = Rails.application.routes.named_routes.to_a
    name = nil
    routes.each do |r|
      name = r[0].to_s if r[1].requirements[:controller] == object.class.to_s.downcase.pluralize && r[1].requirements[:action] == "show"
    end
    name
  end

def nested_object(object)
  name = nested_name(object)
  parent = name.gsub("_", "").gsub(object.class.to_s.downcase, "")
  if object.class.reflect_on_association(parent.to_sym)
    return [object.send(parent), object]
  else
    return object
  end
end
```

So I can do the following:

```
array.each do |element|
  link_to element.name, nested_object(element)
end
```

It works pretty good for me now,...

Answer (score 2):

```
array.each do |element|
  if element.is_a?(Team)
   link_to element.name, url_for([element.department, element])
  else
    link_to element.name, element
  end
end
```

as per [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects). Alternatively, you can use `resources :departments, :shallow => true` but like you mentioned that will give undesirable results for SEO.

Comment: Of cause that would work in this specific case but it wont work genereally. I wrote my own method now,... will post it soon

Answer (score 1):

try this:
`link_to element.name, url_for(element)`

Comment: Try this (tell me if it helped): http://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2012/03/27/a-smarter-rails-url_for-helper/

Comment: It inspired me but I choose another way because all the information are available and I dont want to write them down a secound time like in the post.